# how to reference a currency collection from within a module in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm attempting to make an economy discord bot using `node.js` and I'm trying to move the commands into modules so that I can have a generic/dynamic command handler. How do I reference the currency collection and the models that I created within the main file within the command modules?

---

`index.js` file:

```
const currency = new Discord.Collection();


//defining methods for the currency collection
Reflect.defineProperty(currency, 'add', {
    /* eslint-disable-next-line func-name-matching */
    value: async function add(id, amount) {
        const user = currency.get(id);
        if (user) {
            user.balance += Number(amount);
            return user.save();
        }
        const newUser = await Users.create({ user_id: id, balance: amount });
        currency.set(id, newUser);
        return newUser;
    },
});

Reflect.defineProperty(currency, 'getBalance', {
    /* eslint-disable-next-line func-name-matching */
    value: function getBalance(id) {
        const user = currency.get(id);
        return user ? user.balance : 0;
    },
});
```

---

(In a subfolder) `balance.js`:

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'balance',
    description: 'get balance',
    execute(message, args) {

    const target = message.mentions.users.first() || message.author;
    return message.channel.send(`${target.tag} has ${currency.getBalance(target.id)}`);

    },
};
```

Which currently throws an error on currency, since it's not defined. However, I don't know how to reference the currency collection I made in `index.js`, which also has methods created for it.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this you could attach the `Collection` to your `Client`. Something like

```js
Client.currency = new Discord.Collection()
```

Every time you then reference the collection, instead of doing `currency` you would then run `Client.currency`.

As for accessing the currency object across the files, I'd add another parameter to your `execute` method, something like this:

```js
module.exports = {
    name: 'balance',
    description: 'get balance',
    execute(client, message, args) { // Notice the added "client"

    const target = message.mentions.users.first() || message.author;
    return message.channel.send(`${target.tag} has ${client.currency.getBalance(target.id)}`); // Added "client." in front of "currency", because currency is a property of your client now

    },
};
```

Then, when executing the `execute` method, you'd run `execute(Client, message, arguments);`. Your client would then be passed into the command and be usable in there.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. I tried adding `Client.currency = new Discord.Collection()` and it gives me an error stating that the Client is not defined. I thought perhaps you meant to add it to the existing client var i have `const client = new Discord.Client(); ` but then it gives me an error saying currency is not defined.

Comment: @fl384 When i was talking about `Client`, i of course ment your client instance. As you didn't tell what it was named, i just used `Client` as a placeholder.

Comment: I tried that initially but realize now that I misunderstood the error it threw. This works, thank you!